# How to always save nested items in Rails application (even if they didn't get changed)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, nested-forms

In my Rails 6 application I have this association:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave => true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

Right now, when I save a `project` together with its nested `tasks`, the tasks only get updated when at least one of their attributes changes.

For reasons that are very specific to my application / use case, I want the `tasks` to **always** get updated in the database, though (even if none of them changed at all!) when I hit save.

How can this be achieved?

I was hoping that adding `:autosave => true` would make the difference, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a callback on Project:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord

  before_save :touch_tasks

  def touch_tasks
    tasks.all.touch_all
  end
end
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/touch_all

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this will update the tasks' `updated_at` attributes. It won't run any of the `before_save` callbacks on the `Task` model, though. How can those be triggered?

Comment: Please update your question.  You originally wrote "I want the tasks to always get updated in the database, though (even if none of them changed at all!)" which does not specify that you require before_save to trigger even if no attributes change.